# Should I continue my work on my paper if I found similar kind of paper but with different findings from already published articl?

Tags: research-process

So recently I just came across a similar study that has published on a same topic on which I have been working from past couple of months.
The only difference is that I also include content analysis (qualitative one) in my study?
Feeling worried.
(It's my very first experience to dive in the ocean of research)

Comment: What does your advisor think? What sort of research? Are the data from a different source, like data you've collected?

Comment: It's a review paper and data source is same.

Comment: What does your advisor think?

Comment: I asked him but he didn't reply it yet. There's only 1 year difference in the time period though

Comment: This site is more about answering generalizable problems; for specific research advice we can't really help. Your paper could still be useful to the field or it could be considered completely redundant. Wait for your advisor's response.

Answer (score 2):

You can probably write *a* paper, but it won't be the paper you originally envisioned. You will need to take account of the new published literature and cite it. To be published, though, your paper will need to show some significant (novel) extension or advance over what has already appeared. You can submit, but publish-ability will be the judgement of editors and reviewers.

You might need to be explicit about what the advance over the earlier work is.

You might also, as you work, think about how to extend further what you and they have already done. You may be well placed to do this having come as far as you have. That would increase the likelihood of getting published.

As Bryan Krause implies in a comment, your advisor will probably have useful things to say.

---

Note that parallel research and getting "scooped" is pretty common, especially in "hot" fields.

Answer (score 0):

Now's a good time to stop and talk to your advisor. He/she will have a much better idea of what to do than anyone else, since 1) they are intimately familiar with your research + topic, and 2) they have the experience necessary to say what to do.

If you ask me, based on your brief description, I'd say stop work on your paper and instead focus on reproducing their results. It's unlikely they did exactly the same thing as you. Even if they were investigating the same topic, it's unlikely they used the exactly the same methods. If there's any difference, then you can see if your methods also reach the same results, and comment on any differences. But I'm not your advisor, you should ask them.